# How do you calculate the width of a dbEdit based on fieldsize?

Tags: user-interface, controls, delphi-xe2

I have a form generator that makes all the dbEdits the same width.  The result looks nice, but I think it would be better if the dbEdit width was tailored to the field widths.  I've tried playing with different formulas, but my results have been really hit or miss.  I need something a little more consistent, but haven't been able to figure it out or find anything that says "do it like this:"

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could examine the [`Field.DisplayWidth`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TField.DisplayWidth)/[`Field.Size`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TField.Size) and re-factor the `dbEdit.Width` (e.g. 1 unit of `TField` size equals 15 pixels) against a maximum Width (e.g The containter Panel/Form) using [`dbEdit.ScaleBy`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.ScaleBy) (which internally uses [`MulDiv`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383718%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function).

Comment: I swear, sometimes the simplest solutions are so head-smackingly simple.  Thanks!!